# Maven 3 assembly plugin is very slow

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

After upgrading to maven 3 , my assembly plugin and assembly plugin only takes comparitively more time to copy stuff mostly.

Has anyone faced this issue already, or is there something I need to do so that the performace is faster?

I would be glad to add here , the assebmly plugin config I have and the descriptors used incase there is a need for that.

Thanks

Comment: I have put some workaround information in the answer to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009232/what-sort-of-configuration-issues-or-problems-might-make-maven-assembly-plugin-g/24519615#24519615

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the way your assembly is set up. In general Maven 3 is faster with most tasks but the dependency resolution changed to use aether. I would suggest to upgrade to Maven 3.0.3 and the latest version of the assembly plugin first to see if that fixes it.