# What sort of configuration issues or problems might make Maven Assembly plugin go slowly?

Tags: java, maven, build

Our multi-module Maven project used to take 4-6 minutes to build. Over the past few months, it has increased to 20+ minutes per build. One symptom is that sometimes the build appears to pause until I hit <enter>.  However, the Maven build still runs fine (6 minutes, no pauses) on our build server.

The build command is `mvn clean package -D<profile>`

Some of our plugins include:

- PMD
- FindBugs
- Assembly
- Thrift Compiler
- jspc-maven-plugin
- maven-replacer-plugin

Also, we have an internal Nexus repository.

**Update: Build Logs**

Local Build:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Project Parent ............................. SUCCESS [17.703s]
[INFO] Dependencies ............................... SUCCESS [0.109s]
[INFO] Thrift Service ............................. SUCCESS [1:51.141s]
[INFO] Thrift API Client Sample ................... SUCCESS [14.219s]
[INFO] Application ................................ SUCCESS [14:07.984s]
[INFO] Webapps Parent ............................. SUCCESS [1.250s]
[INFO] Webapp A ................................... SUCCESS [27.547s]
[INFO] Webapp B.................................... SUCCESS [20.672s]
[INFO] Webapp C ................................... SUCCESS [1:14.656s]
[INFO] Assembly ................................... SUCCESS [5:47.219s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24:23.234s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 27 10:47:38 EST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/66M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Build Server (Team City):

```
[02:16:31]: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Reactor Summary:
[02:16:31]: [INFO]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Project Parent ............................. SUCCESS [3.421s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Dependencies ............................... SUCCESS [3.157s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Thrift Service ............................. SUCCESS [41.314s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Thrift API Client Sample ................... SUCCESS [1.220s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Application ................................ SUCCESS [4:09.617s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Webapps Parent ............................. SUCCESS [0.323s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Webapp A ................................... SUCCESS [12.811s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Webapp B ................................... SUCCESS [16.496s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Webapp C ................................... SUCCESS [19.011s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Assembly ................................... SUCCESS [1:45.872s]
[02:16:31]: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[02:16:31]: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[02:16:31]: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Total time: 7:33.655s
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 25 02:16:31 EST 2012
[02:16:31]: [INFO] Final Memory: 42M/317M
[02:16:31]: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update 2**

Here is an empirical analysis of where my build is spending most of its time, using timestamp analysis provided by this bash script: https://gist.github.com/993139

[image: Build Times by Task]

It seems to me that I could disable FindBugs, PMD and Unit Tests for some builds. But I need the final build output - the Assembly. So let me focus my question - what can make Assembly Plugin run slowly?

**Update 3**

As expected, FindBugs, PMD and unit tests cut the build by over 50%

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Project Parent .................................... SUCCESS [13.969s]
[INFO] Dependencies ...................................... SUCCESS [0.094s]
[INFO] Thrift Service .................................... SUCCESS [47.125s]
[INFO] Thrift API Client Sample .......................... SUCCESS [11.922s]
[INFO] Application ....................................... SUCCESS [3:10.922s]
[INFO] Webapps parent .................................... SUCCESS [0.468s]
[INFO] Webapp A .......................................... SUCCESS [18.157s]
[INFO] Webapp B .......................................... SUCCESS [18.437s]
[INFO] Webapp C .......................................... SUCCESS [1:00.672s]
[INFO] Assembly .......................................... SUCCESS [3:55.969s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9:58.609s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 06 10:21:01 EST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/59M
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't think that Assembly should take 4 minutes.  During the assembly phase, I'm seeing a lot of the following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2:single (assembly-full) @ assembly ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: C:\projects\my-project\assembly/src/main/assembly/assembly-full.xml
[INFO] project-2.9.3-SNAPSHOT/config/ already added, skipping
[INFO] project-2.9.3-SNAPSHOT/config/ already added, skipping
[INFO] project-2.9.3-SNAPSHOT/ already added, skipping
[INFO] project-2.9.3-SNAPSHOT/var/ already added, skipping
```

Repeated with each assembly artifact.  Could this somehow be the source of the slowness?

Comment: What does the output at the end of the maven build printout ...there are given times which have been used per module that might be a first indication where to start ...A build which pausing and waiting for a keyboard action sounds really strange ...Are you running only mvn clean package / mvn deploy or are you running mvn site ?

Comment: Updated question with a partial answer. Of course it will take 1/2 hour to get the end-of-build printout :-\

Comment: If you run a build from the command line in windows and then accidentally click in the terminal window it will pause the build (at least in my experience). Hitting enter kicks it to continue. Could this be the cause of the pauses?

Comment: @noahz you didn't answer the question: Are you running mvn clean package or mvn site or what did you try ?PMD and Findbugs can sometimes time consuming ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I edited the question. I'm running mvn clean package.  Of course, if I disable tests, pmd and findbugs, it's faster, but the build server doesn't disable these and yet does not take as long.

Comment: Argh: Timestamps on messages http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-519

Comment: Perhaps it is unit test related? To rule it out try running with -Dmaven.test.skip=true to turn of unit tests. I have seen unit tests open up swing dialogs that hang builds. Also, make sure you are running same version of maven and java on both builds and you are explicitly setting the version on maven plugins in your poms. Also, make sure you are performing the same maven commands on both boxes. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: What kind of machine is your build server and your local machine ? Windows / Unix machine ? My local builds at work are slower than they are on the build server ..? Taken a look on the output: What takes 14 Minutes in your application ? Have you checked a log output via -X ?  And 5 minutes for an assembly looks a little bit strange..? What are you doing there?

Comment: My machine is Windows XP, build server is CentOS :(  That said, the build time didn't used to be so long. It has degraded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First recommendation is to execute the build locally and watch the console. This should help you to easily identify the plugins that take longest.

From my recollection, PMD and FindBugs can take considerable amount of time to run. Same goes for javadoc on larger projects. The other plugins you mentioned I cannot comment on.

Of course, Nexus could be an issue if that runs on a slow system, maybe using slow storage.

Ah, just re-read your post: So it happens on local machines mainly. What is the local machine doing? Does it run into low memory situation? Where the pauses occur could also give an indication.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem (40 minutes on building the assembly for my project). Probing stacktracke gave out that assembly plugin takes a lot of time computing dependencies (computing! not copying!). Commenting out dependencySet should speed up things greatly, if the assembly plugin is slow because of that for your project.

Workaround for maven 3.0.x is to use the goal [dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) with appropriate scope before assembly plugin and then use fileSet to include these copied dependencies into the assembly. This solves performance problem at the cost of some disk space. In my case the assembly build takes now few seconds instead of 40 minutes.

For maven 3.2.x there is no known workaround so far, since it uses that slow way compute dependencies in more places and build freezes for long time before starting doing anything. This makes maven 3.2.x unsuable for the large projects.

Comment: No. This was commertial project in the previous company and I was unable to create a smaller project with same problems now.

Answer (score 1):

For me it got much faster when I upgraded from the assembly plugin from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0 and upgraded my assembly.xml's  tag to newer version (was 1.1.2, now 2.1.0):

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
```

I also made my IntelliJ IDEA to fetch those URL contents of the tag.